# Prompting to save changes then confirm and close the window

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to write a function such that before the window is closed, it will check to see if my button is either in a disabled or enabled state which works fine, but for the second part of closing the window when I click on cancel, the window should stay open and not proceed to close. I am not sure as to where I am going wrong on this one. Thoughts?

```
//Detects and prompt for save changes before closing the window.
window.onbeforeunload = function() {

if ( confirm("Are you sure you want exit the application?") ) {

    if (!document.getElementById("save").disabled) {

        if (confirm("Do you want to save changes?") == true) {
            imts_save_changes()
        }
        else {
            return
        }

    }


}//end if
else { return }//keep the window open

}//end function
```

Comment: You cannot use your own popup/confirm boxes in the `onbeforeunload` event.  Nor can you cancel the closing of the page.  The only thing you can do is return a string.  That string will be put onto a native popup controlled by the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onbeforeunload` method itself shows a popup box for the string that is returned.

ex :

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() 
{
   return "Are you sure you want to exit";
}
```

This returned string will show up in pop up box.

However you can send `asynchronous request` before the return statement to interact with server before closing, but you cannot prevent closing of the browser